# Como pegar o texto do item selecionado no listbox?

Tags: vb.net

Minha tentativa abaixo, está dando object reference, porque? como resolver?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Estou selecionando sim!

Pra popular fiz o seguinte:
lbPerfis.DataSource = Roles.GetAllRoles()
lbPerfis.DataBind()

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema está no `Page_Load`, pois toda vez que é feito um postback o seu método de `Page_Load` é chamado e está sempre recarregando seus dados.

Para evitar de recarregar os dados no `PostBack` basta fazendo isso:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        PreencheListaUsuarios() 
        PreencheListaPerfis()
    End If
End Sub
```

Dessa forma quando ele chegar no `btnDeletarPerfil_click` os dados do listbox estarão normais. :)

Comment: Corretooo, vlw cara!!!

Comment: @WellitonMeneguim Se resolveu seu problema, marque a resposta como a solução. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
If (lbPerfis.Items.Count = 0) = False Then
    If (lbPerfis.SelectedItem Is Nothing) = False Then
         roles.DeleteRole(lbPerfis.SelectedItem.Text.ToString)
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

C# ////////////////////////////////

string Valor = SEU_ListBox.GetItemText(SEU_ListBox .SelectedIndex); //get index

string Valor1 = SEU_ListBOX.GetItemText(SEU_ListBox.Text ); //get Text

MessageBox.Show(Valor);

MessageBox.Show(Valor1);

VB.Net ///////////////////////////////////////

Dim Valor As String = SEU_ListBox.GetItemText(SEU_ListBox.SelectedIndex)

Dim Valor1 As String = SEU_ListBOX.GetItemText(SEU_ListBox.Text)

MessageBox.Show(Valor)

MessageBox.Show(Valor1)